# Arcpy - Updating fields using time.localtime()

Tags: python, arcpy, time

My objective is to change the values under field "DATE_IMPOR" which are currently set at to the current time using time.localtime function. I'm having some problems getting there, above all one line appears to be most problematic "row.setValue("DATE_IMPOR", new_time)".

The field data type of "DATE_IMPOR" is Date, therefore it has to be Date format such as YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD or types supported.

In short, what I get is a Runtime Error.

Here is my script so far:

```
import arcpy
import time

#environnement de travail
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/M1 Geomatique/Programmation II/Dossier"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("ZONE_INONDATION_SYNTHESE_67.shp", "DATE_IMPOR")

#Update cursor
try:
    for row in cursor:
        new_time = time.localtime()[0]
        row.setValue("DATE_IMPOR", new_time)
        cursor.updateRow()

except:
    arcpy.GetMessages()
```

*One note: I wasn't sure where it would be better to ask this question, therefore I have placed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669702/arcpy-updating-fields-using-time-localtime) as well. Apologises for that.

Comment: time.localtime()[0] will give you int - 2015, not Date.
Did you try a simple new_time = time.localtime() ?

Comment: try this line:

    new_time = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: Pankevicius, I tried it and unfortunately it gives me an error.

Comment: Mike, I get the same runtime error as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to find a solution.

Firstly, I changed the way the for loop was being done, making a condition with if so that row.DATE_IMPOR knows what to look for, in this case it was  which I passed it in as (None).

e.g. `if row.DATE_IMPOR == None:
            row.DATE_IMPOR = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            cursor.updateRow(row)`

However, I did not used localtime() as I realized that I would have needed another loop to get the data into proper format, as time.localtime() gives you tuples.

This way was much shorter, effective, and safer if you think about it.